# How to set positions of a node in Cytoscape JS

Tags: javascript

I have this layout options in my JS :

```
                var options = {
                    name: 'preset',

                    positions: undefined, // map of (node id) => (position obj); or function(node){ return somPos; }
                    zoom: undefined, // the zoom level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
                    pan: undefined, // the pan level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
                    fit: true, // whether to fit to viewport
                    padding: 30, // padding on fit
                    animate: false, // whether to transition the node positions
                    animationDuration: 500, // duration of animation in ms if enabled
                    animationEasing: undefined, // easing of animation if enabled
                    ready: undefined, // callback on layoutready
                    stop: undefined // callback on layoutstop
                };


                cy.layout( options                       
                );
```

And I have such a node :

```
{{"id":"Jason","source":null,"target":null},"position":{"x":700,"y":100}}
```

No matter how I change x and y, the node always stays in the same position. How can I change the position of that node? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you do " cy.layout(...)" the position become random.

After throw the layout you should change the position of the nodes manually.

**Idea:**

```
    cy.lock();
    //now set the positions of your nodes
    //cy.elements("...")....x = x;
    //cy.elements("...")....y = y;
    cy.unlock();
```